# Cannot read value of a pending JavaScript promise

Tags: javascript, promise

Noob question. I clearly don't understand promises :-(. I have read extensively but I just cannot seem to get the 789 I originally set. So I have a basic piece of JavaScript that looks as follows:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

    async function WhatIsBrand() {
        let crGbApp = new OzCruisingPresentationConsumer.JavaScript.CrGbApp();
        crGbApp.SearchParameterDataManager.Data.SetBrand(789);
        let brand = await crGbApp.SearchParameterDataManager.Data.GetBrand();
        //console.log(brand.result);
        console.log('-- brand --');
        console.log(brand);
        console.log('-- /brand --');
        console.log('-- brand.result --');
        console.log(brand.result);
        console.log('/brand.result');
        return brand;
    }

    let brand2 = WhatIsBrand();
    console.log('******');
    console.log(brand2);
    console.log('******');
    console.log('######');
    console.log(brand2.result);
    console.log('######');

    console.log('@@@@@@@@@@@@');
    brand2.then(
        bogus => {
            console.log('2222---@@@@@@@@@@@@');
            console.log(bogus);
            console.log(bogus.result);
            console.log('/2222---@@@@@@@@@@@@');
        })
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
    console.log('@@@@@@@@@@@@');
</script>
```

Now in my web console I see as per the attached image:

[image]

**EDIT1:** @Phil, @CertainPerformance - Debugger will tell you the same thing:

[image]

and the promise is still pending and I get nothing back:

[image]

**/EDIT1:** @Phil

**EDIT2:** @CertainPerformance
 - Added `2222---@@@@@@@@@@@@` inside the then()
 - I am still back to `bogus.result` being null even though `bogus` contains the value I want for result which is 789:

[image]

/**EDIT2:** @CertainPerformance

So the value I want is there as somehow the console is completing the promise, I just cannot seem to do it in my own code.

So **brand2** has a ***pending*** promise (yellow) which I need to get to **completed**. However I cannot seem to resolve the promise with either `brand2.then()` or `Promise.resolve(brand2)` as they both return errors.

So what do I "need to do" to brand2 so that I can get the value of result which is `789` instead if undefined (green)? Happy if that also means a simplification of WhatIsBrand().

Comment: *as they both return errors.* What's the problem with `brand2.then`? What exactly is the error? That *is* the right way to do it - if the Promise is rejecting, then you need to handle the rejection, but it doesn't look like that's happening. `brand2.then((brand) => { console.log(brand); }).catch(...`

Comment: The console is a terrible debugging tool as it does not show a snapshot of data at any particular time. Use your browser's debugger to debug your code

Comment: I'm happy to do what I can to help you achieve what you want here, but the question *really is* a duplicate, this sort of thing gets asked multiple times every day - don't take it personally. Indicating that a question has been asked before does not imply anything about whether the question was asked in good faith or was researched, I'm sure it was.

Comment: The `.then` result isn't display in the middle of the `@@@`s because `.then` runs *asynchronously* (like after a `Promise.resolve`). Put the second `@@@` (or both of them) inside the `.then`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Added 2222---@@@@@@@@@@@@ inside the then() - I am still back to bogus.result being null even though bogus contains the value I want for result which is 789.

Comment: For some reason, the object being returned to you from `GetBrand` is populated asynchronously. It's not *just* that you need to call `.then` on (or `await`) the Promise, but also that the `GetBrand` method appears to be buggy, because the object is not populated with the real `result` property when the Promise resolves. You can see here https://i.stack.imgur.com/USQn0.png that `null` is being logged *even inside your* `whatIsBrand`. For this to work, you should fix the `GetBrand` method so that it resolves only when the asynchronous action is fully complete.

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance I will check the GetBrand()